# Degree of a isogeny

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

I have this exercise:

> Let be $\phi:(E_1,O_1)\rightarrow (E_2,O_2)$ a isogeny. Let be
> $\phi=(r_1(x),r_2(x)y)$ its standard affine representation  and write
> $r_1(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ with polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ that do
> not have a common factor. Prove that deg $\phi=$
> max{ deg $p(x)$, deg $q(x)$}.

My professor provided me with this exercise but I don't understand which is the right way to proceed because on the book I'm consulting (Elliptic Curves Number Theory And Cryptography) the fact that I should demonstrate is precisely the definition that gives for '*degree of an isogeny*'.

Instead the definition of degree given by my professor (degree of a homomorphism between elliptic curves) depends on the kenel of the pullback map. So I initially thought about doing this using this definition and then working with the kernel. This approach brings me closer to thinking that there is a relationship between the degree of $\phi$ and the degree of the polynomial $p(x)$ in the numerator, but I just don't understand how the degree of the polynomial $q(x)$ in the denominator can also come into play.
So I thought the path I was following was wrong. Then I also thought of working with dual isogenies to study the degree but it's all too unknown with this particular affine writing of  $\phi=(r_1(x),r_2(x)y)$.

Would any of you have any ideas on how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: An elliptic curve has an function field $K(E)$ generated by $x$ and $y$ satisfying the curve's equation. An isogeny induces and inclusion $\phi^*:K(E_2)\to K(E_1)$ and the *degree* of the isogeny is the index $|K(E_1):\phi^*(K(E_2))|$.

Comment: Yes! I have read this definition from another book (Silverman) but it didn't seem to help me with the proof I have to do. Or rather, I have not been able to relate polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ with the definition linked to the function fields $K(E_2)$ and $K(E_1)$. 
Is there an immediate relationship that allows me to solve the problem but that I cannot see? I've been working on it for almost a week now.

Comment: This is Lemma 9.6.13 in Galbraith book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An isogeny $\phi:E_1\to E_2$ corresponds to an inclusion of function fields
$\phi^*:K(E_2)\to K(E_1)$ and its degree is $d=|K(E_1):\phi^*K(E_2)|$.

Write $K(E_i)=k(x_i,y_i)$ where $x_i$ and $y_i$ satisfy the equation of $E_i$.
Suppose the isogeny has the form $\phi:(x,y)\mapsto (u(x),yv(x))$ where $u$ and $v$
are rational functions. Then $\phi^*(x_2)=u(x_1)$. For each $i$, $|K(E_i):k(x_i)|=2$.
Also $\phi^*k(x_2)\subseteq k(x_1)$. Therefore $d=|k(x_1):\phi^*k(x_2)|
=|k(x_1):k(u(x_1))|$. But this degree is $\max(\deg p,\deg q)$ where
we write $u(x)=p(x)/q(x)$ in lowest terms.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this part: 
Therefore $d=|k(x_1):\phi^*(x_2)|=|k(x_1):k(u(x_2)|$. But this degree is max(degp,degq) where we write $u(x)=p(x)/q(x)$  in lowest terms.
Why is this true and why does it make us realize the desired thesis?

Comment: I believe there is a small error near the end when you write the index $d$ (it should be $\phi^*k(x_2)$).