# Does the first coordinate of a morphism (isogeny) of elliptic curves only depend on the $x$-coordinate?

Tags: elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, isogeny

Let $E,E'$ be two elliptic curves over a field $k$ of characteristic $\neq 2, 3$. Assume that $E,E'$ are given by short Weierstrass equations, and let $f : E \to E'$ be a morphism given by $$f(x,y) = (f_1(x, y), f_2(x, y))$$

**Question**: is it true that $f_1(x, y) \in k(x)$ ? That is, does the first coordinate of $f$ only depend on $x$?
It seems to be the case on all examples I've checked, but I don't see why it should be the case in general.

---

Remark: it is not true if $E' = E$ is not given by a Weierstrass equation, for instance $E : X^3 + Y^3 = Z^3$ is a smooth projective plane cubic curve so it has genus 1 (and has $\Bbb Q$-points), so it is an elliptic curve, but $f :E \to E$ defined by $(x, y) \mapsto (y, x)$ does not have its first component depending only on $x$.

So somehow, we should use the double cover $\pi : E \to \mathbb P^1, (x,y) \mapsto x$ (of degree 2) given by the Weierstrass equation.

Comment: In SAGE documentation, one can read "Both components are returned as elements of the function field F(x,y) in two variables over the base field F, though the first only involves x"... But why is it true?

Comment: In fact, I proved in "Proposition 3.10. Notes_on_Elkies_1994", that any morphism from a hyperelliptic curve $C$ to an elliptic curve $E_0$ has its $f_1$ component that only depends on $x$, not on $y$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3810730/degree-of-a-isogeny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is an isogeny, it is a group homomorphism, so $f(-P) = -f(P)$, or in other words $f(x_P,-y_P) = (f_1(x_P,-y_P), f_2(x_P,-y_P)) = (f_1(x_P,y_P), -f_2(x_P,y_P))$. In particular, $f_1(x_P,-y_P) = f_1(x_P,y_P)$. Therefore $f_1(x,y)$, as a polynomial (it's actually a rational function, but "polynomial" is close enough for our purposes), is an even function with respect to $y$. This means every occurrence of $y$ in $f_1(x,y)$ must be of even degree. But every term of the form $y^{2k}$ is purely a function of $x$, because $y^{2k} = (x^3+ax+b)^k$.

Comment: Something a bit sloppy: $f_1(x,y)=f_1(x,-y)$ is true in the function field, not in $k(x,y)$. I think you need to say that $1,y$ is a $k(x)$-basis of the function field so $f_1=g(x)+h(x)y$ and since $char(k)\ne 2$ you get that $f_1(x,y)= \frac12(f_1(x,y)+f_1(x,-y))= g(x)$.

Comment: OK, I see. I forgot to consider the (hyper)elliptic involution $[-1] : P \mapsto -P$. Thanks, Prof. D. Jao.